# %date% shows incomplete data - Windows CMD

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, cmd

Whenever I try to echo %date% on my machine (Windows7) the output is always the day:

```
C:\> echo The output is: %date%
The output is: Tue
```

However, when I try this to other machines (Windows 7) the output is different:

```
C:\> echo The output is: %date%
The output is: Tue 06/06/2017
```

Anyone had experienced this issue? Any suggestion?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do a `set "date="` and try again. Looks like you created a variable `%date%` by mistake, which overrides the systemvariable.

Comment: go to the control panel -> regional settings and check your date format. Date command is dependent on the registry/control panel settings.

Comment: As @npocmaka said, it looks like you have a custom short date format. On the "Format" tab, click on "Additional setttings...", and on the "Date" tab check the "Short date" entry. It's probably "ddd" for the three-day abbreviation of the day of the week.

Comment: FYI, for cmd.exe in Windows 10, what happens here is that `cmd!GetEnvVar` implements this pseudo-environment variable (it is not a system environment variable) via `cmd!PrintDate`, which gets the user default locale via `GetUserDefaultLCID` and the `LOCALE_SSHORTDATE` format via `GetLocaleInfo`. Then it formats the date string via `GetDateFormat`.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, but this is related to windows 7

Comment: @edd have a look at your environment variables, see what displays as date currently.

Comment: `date /t` has the same underlying implementation, so if that returns "Tue" as well, then it's definitely a locale problem.

Comment: @Stephan Hi, already tried that and still getting `Tue` only

Comment: @GerhardBarnard no environment variable set for date

Comment: @npocmaka thank you. could you please put that answer so I can accept it? the short date use `ddd` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the control panel -> regional settings and check your date format. Date command is dependent on the registry/control panel settings.